# Getting error when trying to rename multiple files with python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have 112 music files in a folder. All of them start with the type of music like `【House】Supermans Feinde   Shine`.

All of them start with that `【` and i want to rename like `House - Supermans Feinde Shine`

I have tried:

```
import os

  for filename in os.listdir("C:/MYMUSICSFOLDER"):

  if filename.startswith("【"):
    os.rename(filename, filename[7:])
```

but I get:

```
Error : sys:1: DeprecationWarning: Non-ASCII character '\xe3' in file C:\MYPROGRAMSFOLDER\ne11.py on line 6,but no enconding declared
```

How do I do that? Rename all of the music files this way?
I tried various code ... but I can't do that.

I have a program thats execute a music when I say "songs" but when I try to do it I get an error; all other functions work perfectly.
Here's the code ...

```
import os,sys,random
import webbrowser
import speech
import sys

 def callback(phrase, listener):
    print ": %s" % phrase

    if phrase == "songs":

        folder = os.listdir("C:/users/william/desktop/music/xkito music")
        file = random.choice(folder)
        ext3= ['.mp3','.mp4','.wmv']

        while file[-4:] not in ext3 :
            file = random.choice(folder)
        else:
            os.startfile(file)
            speech.say('Playing Music')

    if phrase == "open opera":

        webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com')
        speech.say("Opening opera")

    if phrase == "turn off":

        speech.say("Goodbye.")
        listener.stoplistening()
        sys.exit()

print "Anything you type, speech will say back."
print "Anything you say, speech will print out."
print "Say or type 'turn off' to quit."
print

listener= speech.listenforanything(callback)

while listener.islistening():
    text = raw_input("> ")

    if text == "turn off":
        listener.stoplistening()
        sys.exit()
    else:
        speech.say(text)
```

And I'm getting this error when trying to execute the music:

```
pythoncom error: Python error invoking COM method.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 277, in _Invoke_
    return self._invoke_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 282, in _invoke_
    return S_OK, -1, self._invokeex_(dispid, lcid, wFlags, args, None, None)
  File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\win32com\server\policy.py", line 585, in _invokeex_
    return func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\william\Desktop\speech-0.5.2\speech.py", line 138, in OnRecognition
    self._callback(phrase, self._listener)
  File "C:\Users\william\Desktop\speech-0.5.2\example.py", line 21, in callback
    os.startfile(file)
WindowsError: [Errno 2] The system can not find the specified file: '?Glitch Hop?Chinese Man - I Got That Tune (Tha Trickaz Remix) [Free Download].mp4
```

That `?` in the beginning of the name is `【` and `】`

Comment: Just remove the first character of filenames without checking (if you have only files like this), it will be easier.

Comment: So ... i have 112 musics with that character ... i don't time and pacience to do that ... it's because of that i created the program

Comment: I meant do it with the program

Comment: i didn't understand...but what i want to do is  remove the special characters of the name ...

Comment: If you know that ALL of the files in the directory are starting with it, why bother to check it?

Comment: What is the `7` referring to in the last line?

Comment: So thats 7 means after the "【" 7 letters will be deleted !

Comment: No problem, you can delete your own comments if you like.

Answer (score 0):

The error is about handling unicode UTF-8 characters.

I would think that the `filename[7:]` even splits a UTF-8 character between two of its bytes, so that `rename()` sees a partial character.

The right way to fix it is to handle UTF-8 correctly, of course.

Bt one way to work around it altogether is to not work with individual bytes of the string, but with strings only, in a way that the encoding is not relevant:

To convert `【House】Superfoo` to `House - Superfoo`, you can
replace `【` by the empty string, and `】` by `-`.

Use the result of that as the new file name. If the original name is not of the expected format, the name is not changed, and nothing happens. It's not an error, the program does not even notice.

Comment: You are saying i have to leave the line 5 like that ? if filename.startswith(""):

Comment: I'm saying that you do not need to make that distinction, you can handle all names the same.

Comment: i dont know too much about programming .. can you say what i have to do ?

Comment: I don't use Python (or Windows) myself, so no... except something like read an introduction to python - it's a good language choice to start.